# C# OpenFileDialog/CommonOpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, filenames, openfiledialog

I am working on this piece of code that is supposed to open a file dialog and put them into a textbox.

The error is that every time I select more than 1 file while running the app, I get an error in the textbox. If I select only one file, it works fine.

The code is this

```
    private void filePickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the OpenFileDialog object
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
        dialog.Multiselect = true;

        // Check to see if we have a result 
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            filePickerTextBox.Text = dialog.FileNames.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = "Operation cancelled." + "\n" + outputTextBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

I am switching between dialog.Filename.ToString(); (to select one file) and dialog.Filenames.ToString(); to select multiple. When using the latter and selecting a file (whether its only one, or more that one, doesn't matter) the my text box shows System.String[]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thx!

Comment: You should explain which kind of error you get.

Comment: I did, it is not a Visual Studio generated error. It occurs in the textbox when the app is running. Text box shows System.String[] regardless of file input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are selecting multiple files you get a array of files, as your textbox says: `System.String[]`

you could use:

```
filePickerTextBox.Text = string.join(",", dialog.FileNames);
```

Comment: Thx, I am also getting an error on that though. The error displayed CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: edited my answer, the ' indicates a Char value, missed, that string join only accepts string parameter. Looking up the documentation should had let you get an answer too ;)

Comment: Got it. I added a new string = \n to generate a new line between each filename. It all works now. Thx!!

Comment: you're welcome. but please use the msdn documentation more often of you're getting a hint for a possibly fitting method.